# Why can't I use 'as' with generic type parameter that is constrained to be an interface?

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

In the example below (only for demo purpose), if `T` is not constrained with class, then this conversion:

```
var ret = objectA as T;
```

..will cause the following compile error:

> The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because
>   it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint.

I cannot understand why I can't do this. Since I have constrained `T` to be interface `IObject`, the compiler should know that `T` must be an interface type and the `as` operation should be valid.

```
public interface IObject
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}
public class ObjectA : IObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
public class ObjectFactory
{
    public T CreateObject<T>(string id) where T : IObject
    {
        ObjectA objectA = new ObjectA();
        var x = objectA as IObject; // this is good
        var ret = objectA as T; // why this 'as' cannot compile?
        return ret;
    }
    public T CreateClassObject<T>(string id) where T : class, IObject
    {
        ObjectA objectA = new ObjectA();
        var ret = objectA as T; // if T is class, this 'as' can compile
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> since I have constrained T to be interface IObject, compiler should know that T must be an interface type and the 'as' operation should be valid.

No, `T` doesn't have to be an interface type. It has to be *a type that implements the interface*. Consider:

```
public struct Foo : IObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now what would you expect `CreateObject<Foo>("ff")` to do?

With the `class` constraint on `CreateObject`, that call wouldn't be valid because `Foo` isn't a reference type - the compiler knows that `T` is a reference type, so `objectA as T` is okay.